# CSS Switch grid class when screen changed

Tags: html, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation-5

I have a question.
I'm building my own css framework but I have some problem with grid system.
I wanna switch grid class when screen size changed.
Example, In Zurb Foundation we grid:

```
<div class="small-8 medium-4 large-2 columns"> Content </div>
```

So in the large screen, the div's width is 2/12.
In the medium screen, the div's width is 4/12.
In the small screen, the div's width is 8/12.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the media queries that most of the world use this day:)

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

    }

    /* Small Devices, Tablets */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

    }

    /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

    }

    /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    }
```

http://www.asmhijas.com/

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYvEom this is my example and what i wanna ask. if i scale the screen and make it smaller, it goes to another class.

Comment: Thank you vannrith,Yes thats the basics of media queries,when you change your window side..the css will load the given rules at current size.if you want remove or add another class when your window size get small..you need to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 200px)" href="Style/screen_layout_small.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1250px)" href="Style/screen_layout_1024.css" />
```

### screen_layout_1024.css

```
#content {
   width: 1000px;
   height: auto;
}
```

### screen_layout_small.css

```
#content {
   width: 150px;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYvEom this is my example and what i wanna ask. if i scale the screen and make it smaller, it goes to another class.